# Rename file without refactoring in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I can rename a file in VS Code, e.g. `my_script.py` to `my_script2.py`,  and if other scripts import from this file `my_script.py`, all imports are refactored automatically (for example from `from my_script import my_sum` to `from my_script2 import my_sum`). The problem is sometimes I don't need this automatic refactoring. How do I make VS Code to ask me, whether I need refactoring when I rename a file? The same problem happens when moving a file to a new place.

Comment: What programming language?

Comment: That behaviour requires very specific knowledge about every programming language, so it's provided by some extension (whether it's builin or third-party, I don't know).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat python

Answer (score 0):

When you rename the file, you can click the content in the red box, and you can preview the options that need to be reconstructed:

[image]

You can choose to **apply refactoring** or **discard refactoring** by checking it:

[image]

This was mentioned in [pylance's update](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/python-in-visual-studio-code-december-2021-release/#module-rename-with-change-preview) last December. You can also refer to [document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing#_rename-module) for more details.

Comment: In addition, if you click "don't ask again" by mistake, you can refer to [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/discussions/3133) in GitHub. Pylance does not provide the function of restoring settings at present. I think it can only be restored by querying and modifying the database or reinstalling the vscode.

Comment: Even when I click "Don't ask again", it continues to ask again - Is there another way to permanently disable this feature? - Thanks!